# "File already exists" when targeting external drive with mklink

Tags: windows, command-line, external-hard-drive, mklink

I'm trying to relocate a backup folder to an external hard drive with mklink. When I run the command I get the error "the file already exists" (that's the Korean underneath the command):
[image]

(The won sign where the backslash should be, **is** the backslash. It just comes up in Korean on my computer.)

I have literally tried EVERYTHING. I deleted the Backup files and tried it. But doesn't work. What can I do?

Comment: Does E:\Iphonebackup already exist? If so, remove it, because that's the reason why you get the error.

Comment: Had to delete the original Backup folder from Itunes before it could create the link.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the redirected folder first (emptying it out is not sufficient). `mklink` can't transmute directories into junctions; the name has to be available before it can create the junction. Try renaming the `Backup` folder to something else, creating the junction with your first command, then moving any desired files back into the now-redirected folder.